# PHP query with string contain quotes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi i need to do a request to mysql to get some data where filed name = $letter
but the variable $letter may contain ' 
my problem is this i try to use this :

```
$letter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,strtolower($letter));
$us = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM singers where trim(LOWER(name)) = '".$letter."'");
```

My problem is in if $letter was I'm legend, after executing this line it become I\'m legend so it can't be find in database because in database it's stored as i'm legend 
how i can resolve this and get right result.

```
 echo $letter;
      $letter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,strtolower($letter));
        echo $letter;
```

RESULT

i'm

i\'m

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Are you sure that `$letter` is in the database? That's the correct way to escape quotes.

Comment: I don't fink that is going to break your code. Try "select....where name = $letter". Should run just fine

Comment: if i run it directly where name = $letter i get a sql injection

Comment: my problem is this line $letter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,strtolower($letter));

add \ before '
and so he can't find result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you have used

`trim` and `LOWER` in your `column name`

```
"SELECT id FROM singers where trim(LOWER(name)) = '".$letter."'" //why trim and LOWER
```

use this

```
"SELECT id FROM singers where name = '".$letter."'"
```

Also try this like

```
$letter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,strtolower($letter));
$sql = "SELECT id FROM singers where name = '".$letter."'";
// echo $sql; die; print this and run in  phpmyadmin to check
$us = $conn->query($sql);
if ($us !== false) {
echo 'done';
 }
else{ die('failed!' . mysqli_error($conn));}
```

Comment: because $letter is lower
and the problem is that    "I'm legend" != "I\'m legend"
is there any way to escape ' without adding \

Comment: Not working 
i think because he can't find "What\'s Up\'mr Jones"
it's stored as "What's Up'mr Jones"
should i added \ to all field

Comment: no thats not the problem. ok  can you show your table with data??

Comment: have you tried my updated answer also first echo your sql and run into phpmyadmin to see errors

Comment: yes there is no error just can't find
i try with existed value that not contain ' and it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

there is difference between field and value in where 
the \ added is the problem